# Extract all files after wget download

Tags: 12.04, wget

I'm using wget to download a list of files from a URL, here is my command:

```
wget --user='username' --password='mypassword' -i  url.txt
```

This downloads a list of `.gz` files

What I need to do is:

1. Before downloading, delete all files in directory
2. After downloading, unzip all files and delete zipped ones

Is there a command or list of commands which might accomplish this which I can insert into a cronjob? I need to run this once a day.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a one-liner :

```
rm -rfi * && wget -q -O - --user='username' --password='mypassword' -i  url.txt | wget - && find . -name "*.zip" -exec "unzip && rm" {} \;
```

*Don't hesitate to edit/adapt : this could be really wrong as I'm not always very at ease with the `-` pseudo-descriptor and how each application handles it.*

### Some details

Clear current directory.

```
rm -rfi *
```

Get the list, but instead of sending the contents to a file, redirect it to `stdout` (using `-q`, `-O` and the pseudo-descriptor `-`).

```
wget -q -O - --user='username' --password='mypassword' -i  url.txt
```

Download files names of which are being sent from the previous `wget` call. Again, `-` makes refers to the standard input, which is also the previous command's output.

```
wget -
```

Find all zip files in the directory, and execute `unzip` and `rm` on each of them.

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec "unzip && rm" {} \;
```

Comment: Could you explain what this command does and how?

Comment: Sure. I tried my best. Edited.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith you should probably add a caveat that `rm -rf *` will delete ALL files - including any `url.txt` file that is in the working directory - if the `url.txt` file is to be preserved it needs to be moved out of the directory or excluded from the `rm` glob

Comment: It may get more complicated than I thought in the end... Adding `-i` to the `rm` command keeping it "simple".

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a *nix question, than Ubuntu-centric.

In general you'd write a script (using the bash language, or perhaps Python) that handles the task you describe.  One line of the script would be your command, above... the rest would handle the inspection of the directory, deletion, unzipping etc.

Then you'd just use cron (google up crontab) to set the script to run at specific times.

Comment: Actually I've managed to solve the issue, by using ; to separate all my commands to run one after the other. The only question I still can't solve is how to unzip all of the .gz files in the directory, using the normal 'unzip' command doesn't work

Comment: @jc.yin Why are you using `unzip` to unzip a tar.gz file? You should use `tar`. MikeW: This isn't really an answer in it's current form. Could you expand on how to do what you're saying? Also, non "Ubuntu-centric" questions are OK here.

Comment: you could use shell for loop. `for z in *.zip; do unzip $z; done`